# Multithreading background thread goes inactive

Tags: c++, multithreading

First of all, I am a beginner on multithreading, so sorry for basic mistakes.

I stream data from 5 sensors via TCP packages. Each of the sensors initializes and sends data in the background on a thread.

The suppliers SDK is programmed in that way: it queues packages in a buffer and unloads them through a socket. If the CPU is busy and the buffer gets too large (capped at 100 packets), it dropps them and waits for the CPU to unload.

Looking at Sensor 4, this is the bahaviour, that is observed, when operating multiple threads/sensors at the same time:

```
Sensor 0: THIS THREAD IS ACTIVE: 0 ID: 120600400447232 on CPU: 0 
Sensor 0: buff Queue size: 1 
Sensor 0: time for unloading buffer: 0ms 
Sensor 2: THIS THREAD IS ACTIVE: 2 ID: 120600400654848 on CPU: 2 
Sensor 2: buff Queue size: 1 
Sensor 2: time for unloading buffer: 0ms 
Sensor 4: buff Queue size: 101 
Sensor 4: Warning: Client dropped packet due to full buffer... 
Sensor 0: THIS THREAD IS ACTIVE: 0 ID: 120600400447232 on CPU: 0 
Sensor 0: buff Queue size: 1 
Sensor 0: time for unloading buffer: 0ms 
Sensor 2: THIS THREAD IS ACTIVE: 2 ID: 120600400654848 on CPU: 2 
Sensor 2: buff Queue size: 1 
Sensor 2: time for unloading buffer: 0ms
```

This output repeats over and over again, the thread of sensor 4 is inactive for a couple of seconds (I also implemented timestamps at some points).

Of course the Output is not thread-safe but should give a brief overview on what is happening. I assigned sensor 0 to cpu 0, sensor 1 to cpu 1, etc... The programm switches between Thread 0 and 2, while thread 4 is at full buffer. This appears after a short amount of time with 2-5 sensors active. Only one works just fine.

Telling thread 0 and 2 to sleep at this point does not solve the issue. Also this is my lscpu:

x86_64
CPUs: 12
Threads per core: 2
Cores per socket: 6
Sockets: 1

Why is it, that only 2 threads are active at the same time? Is there a way to tell specific threads to "go active"? Or is there a general issue on how I structured the threads?

Thank you and regards

Alex

```
// main:
struct *DataArrayGlobal0 {...}; 
struct *DataArrayGlobal1 {...}; 
// ... 5 times

sensor0 = new sensor("192.168.10.200"); 
sensor1 = new sensor("192.168.10.201"); 
// ... 5 times

sensor0->DataArrayGlobal = DataArrayGlobal0;
sensor1->DataArrayGlobal = DataArrayGlobal1;
// ... 5 times

sensor0->init(); 
sensor1->init(); 
// ... 5 times

// Do some other run methods
// To process they copy the data into their own array
// The threads keep running and are not joined yet

sensor0->deInit();
// .... 5 times
// join threads and clean up


class sensor {
private:
    std::thread start_thread;
    struct myDataArray {...};
    std::mutex mutex;
    // some methods
public:
    struct *DataArrayGlobal;
    void init();
    void start_sensor();
    // some methods
}

void sensor::init() 
{ 
    // some init stuff
    start_thread = thread(&start_sensor, this); // this is an infinite loop until invokeShutdown
}

void sensor::start_sensor() 
{ 
    // do some stuff to create data array myDataArray 
    std::lock_guard guard(mutex); 
    std::copy(myDataArray->begin(), myDataArray->end(), DataArrayGlobal); 
}

void sensor::invokeShutdown()
{
    start_thread.join();
}

void sensor::deInit()
{
    invokeShutdown();
}
```